# PIE Chart is not working in IE 8 with HighCharts

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

I am using Jquery 1.6.2.min and High Charts 3.0.1
     Pie chart is displaying properly in Firefox however in IE8 Slices are not coming. I am working on Ruby on rails :
        Following is the code which I am using for HighCharts :
        ==================================================================================

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#pie1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Testing'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Summary',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function (e) {
                        switch (e.point.name) {
                            case 'Awaiting Validation':
                                $('select[name="rpt_type"]').find('option:contains("To Be Validated")').attr("selected", true);
                                $('#fileFilter').val($('select[name="rpt_type"]').find('option:contains("To Be Validated")'));
                                TTST.searchList();;
                            case 'Not Started':
                                $('select[name="rpt_type"]').find('option:contains("To Be Scrubbed")').attr("selected", true);
                                $('#fileFilter').val($('select[name="rpt_type"]').find('option:contains("To Be Scrubbed")'));
                                TTST.searchList();;
                            case 'Completed':
                                $('select[name="rpt_type"]').find('option:contains("Completed")').attr("selected", true);
                                $('#fileFilter').val($('select[name="rpt_type"]').find('option:contains("Completed")'));
                                TTST.searchList();;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            data: [{
                name: 'Awaiting Validation',
                y: parseInt(scrubbed)
            }, {
                name: 'Not Started',
                y: parseInt(ntStarted)
            }, {
                name: 'Completed',
                y: parseInt(totalComplete),
                sliced: true,
                selected: true
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

In Firefox I am getting the correct pie chart however in IE8 it is showing blank. No slices are coming`

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your example: http://jsfiddle.net/tHwQK/show/ and all works properly in IE8 (8.0.6001.18702). I only replaced data `(parseInt(totalComplete))` with values, because I have no information about variables definitions / values.

ps. Which version of IE do you have?

Comment: I use IE8. Can you please let me know what series value you have changed

Comment: I am getting following error :  Unknown runtime error .. highcharts.js?137118812, line 68 character 443

Comment: In my example ( http://jsfiddle.net/tHwQK/show/ ) ? I need to know which version / revision of IE8 do you have (it is available in about IE or Details)

Comment: x;g.innerHTML=a;return; Line number 68 in HighCharts.js and the error is  "Unknown runtime error". I also changed jquery from 1.6 to 2.10 but I am getting the same issue. One more point I would like to share that I am rendering it on another page.